# I Can Not Get This Code Complile Correctly. What am I doing Wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, class

/* These are going to me my classes, I am having trouble compiling my class? I am not sure what is wrong*/

This Will be my enum class that I will use to in my case statement

```
 public enum Quarter
{
   First,
   Second,
   Third,
   Forth
 }
```

These are my class fields.  I am not too sure about the scanner field I seen this online but it doesn't compile correctly.  Is this a correct way of declaring a scanner type as a field?

```
  public class Quarterly
  {
    private final const ROW = 6;
    private final const COL = 4;
    private Scanner _scanner;


  public Quarterly(Scanner scanner) // This Constructor does not compile either? What am I doing Wrong???
  {
      this._scanner = scanner;
  }
```

This will be a method that would just receive user input.  However I am having trouble with this case statement

```
  private string GetMessage(Quarter quarter, int departmentNumber)
  {
     switch(quarter)
     {
      case Quarter.first:
      return "Enter The First Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
      case Quarter.second:
      return "Enter a The Second Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
      case Quarter.third:
      return "Enter a The Third Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
      case Quarter.forth:
      return "Enter a The Forth Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";

     }

 }
```

This will be an array to get the total of my departments and sum them up

```
 public double GetTotalForDepartments(Quarter quarter)
 {
         double [][] sales = new double [ROW][COL];
         int num = 1;
         double total = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < ROW ; row++)
        {
        // This for statement is taking one column from the array in order to fill with input
             for (int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
             {
                // This will receive sale numbers from the six departments
                System.out.print(message + "[" + num + " ]. . . . . $ ");
                sales[row][col] = _scanner.nextDouble();
                num++;
                // This for statement will sum each department's input
                for (int i = 0; i < sales.length; i++);
                {
                total += sales[row][col];
                }  
             }
        }

return total;
}





/ This will be my main program.

 {
 double test1;
 double test2;
 double test3;
 double test4;

 Scanner  keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 Quarterly helper = new Quarterly(keyboard);

 test1 = helper.GetTotalForDepartments(Quarter.First);
 System.out.println(" Test 1 = " + test1);

 test2 = helper.GetTotalForDepartments(Quarter.Second);
 System.out.println(" Test 2 = " + test2);

 test3 = helper.GetTotalForDepartments(Quarter.Third);
 System.out.println(" Test 3 = " + test3);

 test4 = helper.GetTotalForDepartments(Quarter.Fourth);
 System.out.println(" Test 4 = " + test4 " /n ");
 }
```

Comment: When you try to compile Java it will give you an error. What was the error that you got?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just missing your main declaration?

Comment: For one thing `case Quarter.first:` should be `case Quarter.First`, etc

Comment: you did all the necessary imports? can you post the errors here?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called const in Java. what type of variable is your

```
private final const ROW = 6;
private final const COL = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things.

First, capitalize correctly. (FYI, as a style tip: Constants, such as enum values, are typically all caps, e.g. `FIRST`.)

```
 switch(quarter)
 {
  case Quarter.First:
  return "Enter The First Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
  case Quarter.Second:
  return "Enter a The Second Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
  case Quarter.Third:
  return "Enter a The Third Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";
  case Quarter.Forth:
  return "Enter a The Forth Quarterly Sales For Department [ " + departmentNumber+" ]. . . . . $ ";

 }
```

Second, anywhere you use `Scanner`, do one of the following

1. Add `import java.util.Scanner;` at the top of the file.
2. Refer to it by the full name `java.util.Scanner` instead of `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of missing details about the prob.

but here are the things I noticed.

1. ***const*** - no const in Java
2. it should be

   ```
   switch(quarter){
       case First:
   ```
3. On your second code snippet you're missing "}"
4. Missing Imports